# How to restrict browser back button after logout?

Tags: logout

I'm facing a issue from couple of days, **after logout user can view the login user history details using browser back button**, so how could I resolve this issue. Could you suggest me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Just Put this code in your user history details page

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
  // your user history details code
}else{
  wp_redirect("Your login Page url");
}
```

Comment: Typically the browser back button works without reloading the page from the server though, so I don't think that will help.